# Shape objects won't accept inputted coordinates

Tags: java

I have run into a problem on a piece of homework I have. I've had to make my own `Shape`, `Circle` and `Rectangle` classes. The problem is when a `Point` object is inputted into a circle and rectangle, the Shape class won't accept it in the constructor for a new shape object.

So when I run the main program, the coordinates of the centre of the circle and top corner of the rectangle are null instead of the inputted coordinates.

How can I get `Shape` to accept the point coordinates?

(Sorry if the codes/terminology's wrong, I'm still new to Java)

My shape class:

```
public class Shape {
    private int sides;
    private Color colour;
    private Point coordinates;

    public Shape (int sides, Point coordinates, Color colour) {
        this.sides = sides;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
```

My Circle class:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    private Point center;
    private int radius;

    //constructor for circle class
    public Circle(Point center, int radius, Color c) {
        super(0, center, c);
        this.radius = radius;
```

My rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private int sides = 4;
    private Point topCorner;
    private int width, length;

    //Constructor for rectangle
    public Rectangle(Point topCorner, int width, int length, Color c) {
        super(4, topCorner, c);
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
    }
```

My main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(0,20);
        Point p2 = new Point(20,0);
        Point p3 = new Point(30,30);

        Shape r = new Rectangle(p1, 10, 15, Color.BLUE);
        Shape c = new Circle (p3, 25, Color.YELLOW);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you never initialise `topCorner` or `center`.

In your `Circle` constructor, add

```
this.center = center;
```

In your `Rectangle` constructor, add

```
this.topCorner = topCorner;
```

But, to be honest, what is the purpose of `center` and `topCorner`? `Shape#coordinates` will be the coordinates you are looking for. No need to create another `Point` object in your subclasses when it can be accessible from your super class.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew it'd be something simple, just couldn't work it out. I didn't realise I didn't need to create another `Point` object, thanks for the help :)